# Why the brightness adjustment doesn't affect the full intensity color?

Tags: image-processing, colors, rgb

I have an image with R=255, G=170, and B=180. When I adjust the brightness all intensities got the effect but the R color or any color its intensity equal to 0 or 255.
Can anyone explain what is this issue?

Comment: But.. we don't know how you `adjust the brightness`

Comment: By using Adobe Photoshop

Answer (score 0):

We can see that R=255, G=170, B=180 corresponds to 353degrees/100%/83% HSL representation.

If we assign these value [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsl-to-rgb.htm) and try to adjust L percent, we can see that for this hue/sat combination R keeps 255 value for L>50%, and smoothly changes from 255 to 0 for L range 50% to 0% (this is consistent to conversion formula).